# Ubuntu 18.10 crashes system when trying to play a game

Tags: games, amd-graphics, crash, 18.10

Ever since I updated from 18.04 to 18.10, I'm no longer able to play a game like Heroes of Newerth. As soon as the game start after the picking phase, my system completely shuts off/reboots. Testing with a game like Warsow gives me the same result.

All was fine on 18.04 with the default open source drivers in combination with my AMD RX480 card.

Due to it being a complete crash, I don't quite know where to report what since I have no error nor log messages to go on.

What could be the cause of the problem?
What can I do to gather some more info?
Where would be the appropriate place to report it?

Comment: Be careful next time. And do not upgrade to non-LTS versions. Such new systems as 18.10 can have many upredictable problems with drivers and apps (usually from third-parties, not from official repositories).

Comment: @N0rbert oh that's cold.

Comment: You probably have a problem with your video drivers. Check to make sure that you've got the latest versions installed, and check to see if you want to run the open source driver, or the Nvidia propriatory driver. Also, look in /var/crash to see if you have any crash logs.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for at least a useful reply. The only option I have are the open source drivers, since AMD propitiatory drivers are not yet available for 18.10 (and NVIDIA drivers won't work for an AMD card ;) ). Also, in terms of performance I have no need for any other driver than the open source ones. I have been using nothing but stock Ubuntu drivers for several releases now. Nothing of any use is available in /var/crash. I suppose because the system simple shuts off in an instant, leaving no room to log anything.

Comment: Try temporarily adding `nomodeset` (right next to `quiet splash`) to your kernel line in GRUB, and see what happens. Your video resolution may be screwed up, but I just want to see if the computer shuts down. You can do this by hitting the `e` at the GRUB menu.

Comment: With this parameter added I don't even get to load the games correctly to get them to crash the machine. As an additional test I tried a wayland session instead of the xorg session I normally use. The result is the same, a hard crash of the system. An additional observation:  in about 50% of the crashes it is just turning the system off completely. In the other 50% it reboots the system and it's the BIOS telling me about a probable power issue. To what extend could this issue be PSU related as a result of a software update?

Comment: I disabled the systems anti-surge protection, the message that came up in the 50% of the cases where the system rebooted instead of shutting down, in the BIOS as a test. No change again, the system just turns off. In addition to that I gave the [Oibaf ppa](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers?field.series_filter=cosmic) driver updates a try, but alas. [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=cosmic) has not yet added any Xorg updates to try. Would filing a bug against xserver-xorg-video-radeon be the logical next step?

Comment: You can try and reset the power management unit by unplugging the computer from AC mains, removing all batteries if this is a laptop, and holding down the power key for about 10 seconds. See if that makes any difference. Report back. Send comments to include @heynnema, or I'll probably miss them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the PSU to rule out the possibility of a broken PSU just in case, hence the delay. While it was a risk, I needed an excuse you buy a quieter one anyway. And guess what @heynnema? No more crash. While I find it difficult to believe that a software update uncovers an issue with the PSU, I suppose I just have to accept that it was slowly dying. Thank you for your effort anyway.